# Haskell - response code of simpleHTTP method

Tags: url, haskell, csv

I've written the following Haskell code to download the CSV file (daliy prices) available on yahoo finance web site . In the last part of the code, there's a case statement. I would like to know when actually "rcode" contains the "Left" value. I've mentioned three cases, but all of them refer to "Right" values. I may be wrong. I'm referring to the HTTP response codes available on the following web site.

```
downloadCSVFile ::String-> IO (Bool,String)
downloadCSVFile company_code=do 
                             let a="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" ++ company_code
                             let b=simpleHTTP $  getRequest a 
                             src <- ( b >>= getResponseBody)
                             rcode <- fmap rspCode <$> b
                             case rcode of
                                     Right (2,_,_) -> return (True,src)
                                     Right (4,_,_) -> return  (False,"Invalid URL..")
                                     Right (5,_,_) -> return  (False, "Server Error")
```

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40132?hl=en

Comment: I copied your code into the question to make it easier to read.

Comment: I didn't get that ....you mean, to where ?

Comment: I mean that I copied your code from the URL to be inline in the question.

Comment: now only realised that :) Thank you :!

Answer (score 1):

The `Result a` type that gets threaded around is an alias for `Either ConnError a`.

You'll get a `Left` value if the `HTTP` client library had some actual problem when connecting to the server. If it successfully connected to the server and received a HTTP response code from the server, that will always be a `Right` value.

See the [Network.HTTP documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.10/docs/Network-HTTP.html) for more details.

To handle the error cases, do something like this:

```
case rcode of
    Left err      -> return (False, "Connection error: " ++ show err)
    Right (2,_,_) -> return (True,src)
    Right (4,_,_) -> return  (False,"Invalid URL..")
    Right (5,_,_) -> return  (False, "Server Error")
    Right code    -> return  (False, "Unexpected code: " ++ show code)
```

I also added a "catch-all" case in case you get an unexpected response from the server.

Comment: If You don't mind , can you add that part to the above code ? The thing is that I'm not that good enough at data communication related things. and, I've added three "Right" values.....r they ok ? do I need to change them to "Left" values ?

Comment: Then you mean to say that no HTTP response code will be received if it could not successfully connect to the server...???  
That means , it has to be something like 
......
Right (5,_,_) - > .....                                          Left x -> .......

Comment: Thank You so much !! But there are some other two codes available in HTTP (as per the web page I've posted above). That are (1,_,_) and (3,_,_) . Those two are not errors but provisional response and redirect respectively. Those two also will be caught by "catch-all".....is it OK ?

Comment: If you know what a code means and can handle them better with a custom case, then you should add one.